# Showing that this topology is the same as the product topology on $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the product topology on $X \times Y = \{(x,y) : x \in X, y \in Y\}$ generated by the basis $\widetilde{\mathcal{B}} = \{U \times V : U \in \mathcal{T}_{_X}, V \in \mathcal{T}_{_Y}\}$.

Suppose that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis on $X$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis on $Y$ and consider the basis $\mathcal{D} = \{B \times C : B \in \mathcal{B}, C \in \mathcal{C}\}$ for topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $X \times Y$.

I want to show that $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ are the same topology. 
I've already shown that $\mathcal{D}$ is a basis, and I've also shown that $\mathcal{T}' \subset \mathcal{T}$.

I'm stuck on how to show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$. The proof in my text says:

> Let $W \in \mathcal{T}, (x,y) \in W$. We want to show that $\exists D \in \mathcal{D} \text{ such that } (x,y) \in D \subset W$.

The proof then goes on to show that this really is true and concludes that we are done.

Why does this show that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$?

Comment: It shows that $W$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal D$. Combining this with the fact that $\mathcal D \subset \mathcal T'$ and that $\mathcal T'$ is closed under union, it follows that $W \in \mathcal T'$.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why $W \in \mathcal{T}'$.

Comment: It's what I wrote in my comment, I'll try to write it a bit differently. $W$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal D$. Each element of $\mathcal D$ is an element of $\mathcal T'$, and so $W$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal T'$. Since $\mathcal T'$ is closed under union, it follows that $W$ is an element of $\mathcal T'$.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the effort to re-explain that, I've got it now. Would you mind turning that into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why $W \in \mathcal T'$, first note that $W$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal D$. Each element of $\mathcal D$ is an element of $\mathcal T'$, and so $W$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal T'$. Since $\mathcal T'$ is closed under union, it follows that $W$ is an element of $\mathcal T'$.